# React native active sidebar menu item

Tags: javascript, react-native

In react native, I made a drawer sidebar menu with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Left, Right, Icon, Body } from 'native-base';

import styles from './styles'

const menuItems = [
    {
        name: "Home",
        route: "Home",
        icon: "home",
    },
    {
        name: "Nieuws",
        route: "News",
        icon: "paper",
    },
    {
        name: "Coureurs",
        route: "Drivers",
        icon: "person",
    },
    {
        name: "Teams",
        route: "Teams",
        icon: "people",
    },
    {
        name: "Foto's",
        route: "Photos",
        icon: "images",
    },
    {
        name: "Resultaten",
        route: "Results",
        icon: "clipboard",
    },
    {
        name: "Kalender",
        route: "Calendar",
        icon: "calendar",
    },
];

export default class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onMenuPress = this.onMenuPress.bind(this);
        this.state = { currentPage: 'Home' };
    }

    componentDidUpdate () {
        this.render();
    }

    onMenuPress = (item) => {
        this.setState({ currentPage: item });
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Container style={styles.container}>
                <Content>
                    <List
                        dataArray={menuItems}
                        renderRow={item =>
                            <ListItem style={this.state.currentPage == item.name ? styles.activeMenuItem : styles.menuItem} button onPress={() => this.onMenuPress(item.name)}>
                                <Icon name={item.icon} style={this.state.currentPage == item.name ? styles.activeMenuIcon : styles.menuIcon} />
                                <Text style={this.state.currentPage == item.name ? styles.activeMenuItemText : styles.menuItemText}>
                                    {item.name}
                                </Text>
                            </ListItem>
                        }
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

My styles:

```
export default {
    container: {
        backgroundColor: "#48545A",
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    menuItem: {
        marginLeft: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#48545A",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#5B686E',
    },
    activeMenuItem: {
        marginLeft: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#FAA41A",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#5B686E',
    },
}
```

[This is what I get on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwJAN.png)

I tried to make an active menu item, so it changes the current menu item and give it different styles. I added a state, which will contain the currentPage.

My listitems have shorthand if statements to check if currentPage is equals to the current item.name.

```
style={this.state.currentPage == item.name ? styles.activeMenuItem : styles.menuItem}
```

Now, when I click a menu item, it doesn't update the sidebar. The state does change, checked that with a simple `alert`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with React Native in particular but this style prop seems a bit off - `style={this.state.currentPage == item.name ? styles.activeMenuItemText : styles.menuItemText}`. What is the value of `styles.menuItemText` and `styles.activeMenuItemText`. It must be an object in order for it to work

Comment: I import the styles `import styles from './styles';` I added my styles to my question

Comment: In this example - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html they use something called `StyleSheet.create` maybe that could help you

Comment: I understand the styles and how I add them, but the styles are not the problem.

Comment: try removing `componentDidMount` altogether because calling `render` method is a no-op

Answer (score 0):

Your using double equals instead of triple equals. Always use triple equals. I would change this first because that could be the issue.

Also double check your press event is getting triggered.

Comment: I changed dubble equals to tripple, but doesnt work either. I also checked the onPress event is getting triggerd.

Comment: Console.log out what "this.state.currentPage" is and what "item.name" is.